# ARRAY_REMOVE() in Snowflake?

Tags: javascript, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

Postgresql has the ARRAY_REMOVE function to remove elements from an array. How can I do this in Snowflake?

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_remove

Answer (score 2):

### Update

As noted by data_steve, ARRAY_EXCEPT() was introduced 2022/11

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/6-37-Release-Notes-November-10-11-2022

---

You can create a JS UDF. For it to work with any types, you'll need to cast the value to be removed to variant:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_remove_js(ARR variant, VAL variant)
returns array 
language javascript
as '
return ARR.filter(function(item) {
    return item !== VAL
})
';
```

Testing with strings, integers, and floats:

```
select array_remove_js(parse_json('["a", "b", "c", "a"]'), 'a'::variant);

select array_remove_js(parse_json('[4, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4]'), 4::variant);

select array_remove_js(parse_json('[4.3, 1.1, 4.2, 0.1, 3.3, 0.2]'), 0.2::variant);
```

Comment:  I was thinking about null handling like: `select array_remove_js(parse_json('[1,2,3, null,1,2,3]'), null::variant);` but then I would probably use `ARRAY_COMPACT`  `SELECT ARRAY_COMPACT(parse_json('[1,2,3, null,1,2,3]'))` instead.

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_remove

Answer (score 2):

Snowflake has this function [ARRAY_REMOVE()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_remove)

Comment: This would be my preference, as well, although you say that you can't order the array, but there is an order by option with that function.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to remove elements from ARRAY using either by element `ARRAY_REMOVE` or element's position `ARRAY_REMOVE_AT`:

```
SHOW BUILTIN FUNCTIONS LIKE 'ARRAY_REMOVE%';
```

| name | arguments |
| --- | --- |
| **ARRAY_REMOVE** | ARRAY_REMOVE(ARRAY, VARIANT) RETURN ARRAY |
| **ARRAY_REMOVE_AT** | ARRAY_REMOVE_AT(ARRAY, NUMBER) RETURN ARRAY |

---

Usage:

```
SELECT ARRAY_REMOVE(['a', 'b', 'c'], 'b'::VARIANT);
-- [   "a",   "c" ]

SELECT ARRAY_REMOVE_AT(['a', 'b', 'c'], 1);
-- [   "a",   "c" ]
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this update - though I need to chase why they are not in the docs now :)

Comment: @FelipeHoffa There is also `ARRAY_GENERATE_RANGE(from, to, step)`  https://stackoverflow.com/a/76141550/5070879 that is not in docs :) I love hidden gems that are present in `SHOW FUNCTIONS` :)

Comment: do you keep a running diff? :)

Comment: Thanks!  Documented: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_remove

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake's [`ARRAY_EXCEPT`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_except) handles this nicely in the cases where array is a distinct set of values.

However, if there are multiple values in the array, it will only remove as many of that value as is passed into the `<array_of_elements_to_exclude>` param.

Comment: fyi https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_remove