# SQL: select MIN date from array column that is greater that post date

Tags: sql, arrays, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
user_id|.  no_issue_date|  issue_dates_array
1.          2021-01-01.    [2021-01-10, 2021-01-11, 2021-02-14, 2021-03-14, 2021-03-20]
1           2021-02-03     [2021-01-10, 2021-01-11, 2021-02-14, 2021-03-14, 2021-03-20]
1.          2021-03-17.    [2021-01-10, 2021-01-11, 2021-02-14, 2021-03-14, 2021-03-20]
2           2021-04-26     [2021-05-10, 2021-05-20, 2021-05-29]
2           2021-05-18     [2021-01-10, 2021-01-20, 2021-02-29]
```

And I would like to do a SQL CTE that could return the MIN(`date` from `issue_dates_array` column) that is greater than the `issue_date`, so my end result would look like the following:

```
user_id|.  no_issue_date|  issue_dates_array                                            | result
1.          2021-01-01.    [2021-01-10, 2021-01-11, 2021-02-14, 2021-03-14, 2021-03-20]   2021-01-10
1           2021-02-03     [2021-01-10, 2021-01-11, 2021-02-14, 2021-03-14, 2021-03-20].  2021-02-14
1.          2021-03-17.    [2021-01-10, 2021-01-11, 2021-02-14, 2021-03-14, 2021-03-20]   2021-03-20
2           2021-04-26     [2021-05-10, 2021-05-20, 2021-05-29]                           2021-05-10
2           2021-05-18     [2021-05-10, 2021-05-20, 2021-05-29]                           2021-05-20
```

Is there a way to do it just in SQL /snowflake SQL?

Comment: If using SQL, why not normalize your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way is :

```
select user_id,no_issue_date,issue_dates_array 
     , min(case when d.value > issue_date then d.value end) as result
from table t
lateral flatten (input => t.issue_dates_array) d
group by user_id,no_issue_date,issue_dates_array
```

Answer (score 2):

Custom function approach:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_min(ARR variant, VAL variant)
RETURNS variant
LANGUAGE javascript
AS 'return Math.min.apply(Math, (ARR.filter(function(item) {return item > VAL})))';
```

Query:

```
SELECT *, 
 DATE(AS_INTEGER(array_min(t.issue_dates_array, t.no_issue_date::variant))) AS result
FROM t;
```

[image]

Data prep:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t(user_id TEXT, no_issue_date DATE, issue_dates_array ARRAY)
AS
          SELECT 1, '2021-01-01'::DATE, array_construct('2021-01-10'::DATE, '2021-01-11'::DATE, '2021-02-14'::DATE, '2021-03-14'::DATE, '2021-03-20'::DATE)
UNION ALL SELECT 1, '2021-02-03'::DATE, array_construct('2021-01-10'::DATE, '2021-01-11'::DATE, '2021-02-14'::DATE, '2021-03-14'::DATE, '2021-03-20'::DATE)
UNION ALL SELECT 1, '2021-03-17'::DATE, array_construct('2021-01-10'::DATE, '2021-01-11'::DATE, '2021-02-14'::DATE, '2021-03-14'::DATE, '2021-03-20'::DATE)
UNION ALL SELECT 2, '2021-04-26'::DATE, array_construct('2021-05-10'::DATE, '2021-05-20'::DATE, '2021-05-29'::DATE)
UNION ALL SELECT 2, '2021-07-18'::DATE, array_construct('2021-05-10'::DATE, '2021-01-20'::DATE, '2021-05-29'::DATE);
```

Inspiration: [ARRAY_REMOVE() in Snowflake? by Felipe Hoffa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68748323/5070879)

Answer (score 1):

You can unnest the array, which in Snowflake uses `flatten()`.  I would first try to do this using a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select min(value)
        from table(flatten(input => t.issue_dates_array))
        where value > no_issue_date
       ) as result
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

0Alternative option using [ARRAY_INTERSECTION](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_intersection.html) and [ARRAY_AGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_agg.html).

The idea being create an array using the NO_ISSUE_DATE then intersect with the ISSUE_DATES_ARRAY and select the first record of resulting array - using [0].

[image]

```
SELECT 
 NO_ISSUE_DATE
,ISSUE_DATES_ARRAY
,ARRAY_INTERSECTION(ARRAY_AGG(A) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY A),ISSUE_DATES_ARRAY)[0] RESULT
FROM(
    SELECT NO_ISSUE_DATE , DATEADD(DAY,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NO_ISSUE_DATE ORDER BY SEQ4())-1,NO_ISSUE_DATE) A ,ISSUE_DATES_ARRAY
    FROM t  , TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => (100) ))   
 ) 
GROUP BY 
    NO_ISSUE_DATE  
    ,ISSUE_DATES_ARRAY
```