# Generate Series Alternative for Snowflake works but generates an incomplete list

Tags: list, time, schema, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, generate

I am looking into creating a list, where I see how many IDs were generated in a given hour. Because I want to display the hours from 8 to 21 in advance independent of the hour of the date, I used generate series and now need to find the equivalent for Snowfake. This is my query:

```
series as  (
    SELECT seq4() as Hour 
    FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(rowcount => 21)) 
    where Hour between 7 and 20 
    ORDER BY Hour), 
ID_table as (
    select extract(hour from date) as "Hour", 
    count(ID) as "Count" 
    from ID_table 
    group by 1) 
 select (Hour.Hour) + 1 AS "Hour",
 id."Count", 
 from series as Hour
 left join ID_table as id on id."Hour" = Hour.Hour 
 order by Hour.Hour;
```

For some reason I only get the Hours 8 to 16, however, I want it to display the hours 8-21, what could be the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always consider that SEQ() functions do not guarantee gaps, so for generating the range, I suggest you to use ROW_NUMBER() function:

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Generate-gap-free-sequences-of-numbers-and-dates

Anyway, when I test it, I see it returns expected numbers:

```
SELECT seq4() as Hour FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(rowcount => 21));
-- returnns numbers from 0 to 20

SELECT seq4() as Hour FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(rowcount => 21)) where Hour between 7 and 20 order by hour;
-- returnns numbers from 7 to 20

with series as (SELECT seq4() as Hour FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(rowcount => 21)) where Hour between 7 and 20 ORDER BY Hour)
select (Hour.Hour) + 1 AS "Hour"
from series as Hour;
-- returnns numbers from 8 to 21
```

Could it be something with the browser/UI?

Comment: thanks a lot the row_number approach worked!

Answer (score 0):

Generating range of integers `[start, end)` with `ARRAY_GENERATE_RANGE(start, end, step)`:

```
SELECT ARRAY_GENERATE_RANGE(7, 21);
-- [  7,   8,   9,   10,   11,   12,   13,   14,   15,   16,   17,   18,   19,   20 ]
```

Transforming into rows:

```
SELECT VALUE::INT
FROM TABLE(FLATTEN(ARRAY_GENERATE_RANGE(7, 21)));
-- 7
-- 8
-- ...
-- 20
```